# Create input field dynamically and need to send value

Tags: php, forms

I am not writing my exact code here but I am giving the basic idea.

```
<form action="thispageagain.php">

for($i=0; $i<$n; $i++){
echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"view post\" />";
}

</form>
```

Now when someone click on view post i have to send post id for that post. How can I do this. I have to use post method here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to send the post id right... if i did not get your question wrong then you can do it as follow.. i assume that $i represents your post id that you want to send.

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['formsubmitted']) && $_POST['formsubmitted'] === 'Y'){
      $postId = array_keys($_POST['btnviewPost']);
      print_r( $postId);
  }
?>
<form action="" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="formsubmitted" value="Y" />
 <?php for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){?>
    <input type="submit" value="view post" name="btnviewPost[<?php echo $i?>]" />
 <?php }?> 
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your coding style also

Answer (score 0):

Each submit input field needs to be in its own form.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
    echo "<form action="thispageagain.php">";
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"view post\" />";
    echo "</form>";
}
```

Comment: I need the for loop to be inside the form.

Comment: @AshiqurRahman Why do you need all input fields in one form? If you do that then on any submit you'll end up submitting all post id values to your page. Is that what you want?